# Forward a All Request to Delegate Handler in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a view written in MVC. I am catching all request in a `CustomRouteFilter`'s following method

```
public class CustomRoutesHandler : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Here I want to forward all request to a custom `DelegateHandler`'s `SendAsync()` method. Can anyone help me.

```
public class RequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can call a method directly on RequestHandler from CustomRoutesHandler, then the following works:

**CustomRoutesHandler:**

```
public class CustomRoutesHandler : RouteBase
{
    Route route;
    public CustomRoutesHandler(Route route)
    {
        this.route = route;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        HttpResponseMessage response = requestHandler.SendAsync(request).Result;
        return route.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

**RequestHandler:**

```
public class RequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
        return SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        tsc.SetResult(response); 
        return tsc.Task;
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig:**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        Route route = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.Remove(route);
        routes.Add(new CustomRoutesHandler(route));
    }
}
```